# Accessing both branches of preprocessor conditions in Roslyn syntax trees

Tags: c#, roslyn

Trying to parse C# code with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.0.0, I noticed that Roslyn's `SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree` accepts preprocessor symbols in `CSharpParseOptions`, and produces a syntax tree with an unparsed `DisabledTextTrivia` encompassing the inactive branch.

My question is the following: is there a way to make Roslyn fully parse both branches? If not, why not exactly? I expected the preprocessor symbols to be provided to Roslyn at the compilation phase, rather than at the syntax parsing phase.

A use case would be a refactoring tool that modifies code in disabled code branches (as ReSharper does).

Comment: The set of enabled preprocessor simples affects the shape of the parse tree (eg, if you have a `{` inside a `#if`), so it must be handled at parse time.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you have any suggestions for dealing with the disabled fragment? On possible idea is to parse the source once with no symbols, detect the symbols and reparse the source with different symbol permutations. This seems pretty horrible and inefficient though.

Comment: Yes; the only way to do this is to parse with every possible combination of symbols.  Since they may result in completely different syntax trees, there isn't any other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SLaks pointed out above, the two different branches can lead to different syntactic structures, which is why preprocessor symbols have to be taken into account at parse time. The only possible way to work on disabled branches is to parse for every possible combination of symbols.